# Should bundle identifiers be lowercase or camelcase?

Tags: ios, macos, bundle-identifier

Say I have an app named "Foo Bar", should the bundle identifier be `com.tyilo.foobar` or `com.tyilo.FooBar`?

What is the most normal and what does Apple do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do any but to make life simpler and prevent common mistakes it's just easier to keep it all lower case..

But it's entirely up to you what case you use?. The only gain from using lower case is what I mentioned above

Answer (score 2):

I would make it the lower case not only to make your life simpler but also because bundles are reverse domain name and URLs are case insensitive up to and including the TLD (com/org/net) and most browsers display URLs as all lowercase.

Also if you look at Apple's sample code they use all lower case.

`com.example.apple-samplecode`

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's own generation process, it can be both. Apple generates the automatic bundle ID in Xcode like this:

if your company name is Example, and...

- your app name is "foobar", your bundle ID will be com.example.foobar
- your app name is "FooBar", your bundle ID will be com.example.FooBar
- your app name is "Foo Bar", your bundle ID will be com.example.Foo-Bar

Of course, you can set your own bundle ID to something else other than the default, this is just how the automatic process works.