# -temp-caseinsensitive-rename in Bundle Identifier

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I've created app named myap. Along with this app created Bundle Identifier in AppID com.mydomain.myapp and created new provisioning profile. After that I have noticed my app is misspelled so I renamed from "myap" to "myapp", expecting the bundle identifier will change accordingly. However to my surprise I got assigned bundle identifier as "com.mydomain.myapp-temp-caseinsensitive-rename". What is this?
I tried to explicitly change bundle identifier in targets info tab, but the app is moaning. 
What should I do to put the app and its bundle on right track?

Comment: [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848712/changed-project-name-in-xcode-causing-naming-error)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In XCode, go to Build Settings and change the Product Name under Packaging