# Changed project name in Xcode causing naming error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.5, xcode4.6

My old name consisted of a camel case type name similar to this

**MyApp**

I then changed it to

**Myapp** 'notice the A is now non-caps'

I changed this by clicking `MyApp` name in the navigator menu and changing it, up came a help box asking me to do system wide changes I clicked YES!

but now when I build this application its saying the name of my app is:

**Myapp-temp-caseinsensitive-rename**

I am now wondering how do I get rid of the -temp-caseinsensitive-rename portion?

Comment: Have you checked the product name in build settings? Is it pointing to Myapp?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Check the product name in build settings and make sure everywhere it is Myapp. If that is done,

- Close your project -> go to finder.
- Right click on your .xcodeproject file and click on show package
  contents.
- Then right click on your project.pbxproj and open it in some text
  editor.
- Then search for Myapp-temp-caseinsensitive-rename and manually rename
  it.
- Save it after changing and then reopen the project.

Make sure you have taken a back up of your project before doing this.

Comment: dont listen to my last comment.. found another 12 entries.. I fould that they differe bettween and underscore and a hyphen... bloody things

Comment: ledgen.. took abit of work.. tried it a couple of times... the easiest thing to do in the end is to change the name completely from its initial value, Then change it back to the same name with the case difference.. that way once you change the things needed to be changed in xcode like target etc you follow your instructions but instead of having to remove all that crap about caseinsesnsitive etc etc.. you just change the case of the letter or letters in question. .. and everything is names as it should be.

Comment: I found some of these rogue strings inside a .xib file as well. Worth checking those with an editor, too.

Comment: @ghr, Yes you are correct. This needs to be checked in all files. You can open xib file also in text editor for this.

Comment: You'll also probably need to rename the `yourApp-Info.plist` and `yourApp-Prefix.pch` files as well.

Comment: Problem is still here with xcode 5. You would've think that all of these issues should be resolved by now...

Comment: This just happened to me after renaming a project, I tried restarting xcode and reopening the project and it now builds!

Comment: excellent solution, just rename every instance in that text file. worked beautifully my app is now validated properly against my certificate!

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue, but it only affected a Target that got affixed with "case-insensitive-rename". If you have a similar situation, just do the following (using XCode 5):

1) click on your project in the left.
2) expand to see all your targets by clicking the tiny button

[image: step 2 - tiny expand button]

3) rename affected Target(s).

[image: step 3 - rename]

4) Save project. Then for OCD brownie points, open your project in a text editor and do a ctrl-f for any "insensitive" or similar to ensure everything's resolved.

Comment: What do you use to pixelate text like that?

Answer (score 5):

Go to `project -> Build Settings -> Search "Packaging"` and change the **product name** key.

If that does not work, repeat but within your target, so `Targets -> YourApp -> Build Settings -> Search "Packaging"`

Voila.

Answer (score 4):

None of these worked for me,
I found this post and it worked, and it was the simplest. So I guess the solution depends on how you got yourself in the mess in the first place :)

[-temp-caseinsensitive-rename in Bundle Identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820022/temp-caseinsensitive-rename-in-bundle-identifier)

Answer (score 1):

Try building a new scheme of your app by selecting on project name on top of xcode after play and stop button. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

In my case **hold down the option key** on the keyboard and go to

> Project -> Clean Build Folder (option+shift+command+k)

After that **close and reopen Xcode**.