# Finished running on iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5

Since Yesterday when I build and run my app I m getting `build Succeeded` and `Finished running 'appname'on iphone simulator` and then it stops running. When I `reset the contents of simulator` then it shows me the app.This happens to me from yesterday.Before that I used to run as many apps in my simulator.But now when I reset contents then only I can run a new app.

I dont understnd whats wrong with xcode..?
Is there a way that I don't reset content settings everytime for a new app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932750/ios-simulator-failed-to-install-the-application/13006893#13006893

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

1.Manually launch the iOS Simulator.

2.From the "iOS Simulator" menu, click "Reset content and settings",

3.Close and rebuild your app.

Comment: The same I did.But everytime I switch to a new app I need to click "Reset content and settings" which I dont wantto do.This was not the case earlier with simulator.Earlier I can switch to many apps without clearing the content..Will I need to change any settings ?

Comment: Plz provide the version of Xcode and Simulator you are using.have a look at this link http://hiediutley.com/2011/03/10/xcode4-is-your-old-project-hanging-in-the-simulator/

Comment: Xcode 4.5 and ios simulator 6.This issue started when I renamed one of my app.Can u tell me whether any of the settings might have changed now due to which this issue is occuring,?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848712/changed-project-name-in-xcode-causing-naming-error

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing the following..
- clearing the derived data
- resetting the simulator
- shutting down the simulator and having it be launched by xcode after that

I did figure out what it was I was doing to get into the problem. I was trying to copy a folder called Resources to the bundle. Twice doing that got me into the mess. Third time I renamed the folder to just Res and it seemed to work. Seems like "Resources" is a special name for folders in a bundle and you can't use it for your own content.