# Error: .temp_caseinsensitive_rename in Targets name

Tags: ios, objective-c, setting

I changed the name of my project in Identity and Type this cause my target's name to have .temp_caseinsensitive_rename in the end. I searched for solutions, some suggests to manually change the affected files but I notice that the target's name still remains. When I check the Build Settings, all the Settings row still have the .temp_caseinsensitive_rename in the end of my projects name. How can I change it?

Comment: Look for this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12848841/2988783