# Validating package error in Xcode

Tags: xcode, entitlements

I can not figure out why this is giving me this error. I know I have a valid .mobileprovision that is active. My app is ready for uploading in Itunes connect and I have selected the provision in my build setting. Can anyone please help me figure this out.

Comment: Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. The Bundle contains a key that is not included in the provisioning profile:'inter-app-audio' in Payload.

Comment: Your package contains a file 'welldoneskatesupply.temp_caseinsensitive_rename.temp_caseinsensitive_rename 'with a name that cintains leading or trailing whitespec characters.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the bundle identifier also this issue can be produced because of invalid private key.

Comment: Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. The Bundle contains a key that is not included in the provisioning profile:'inter-app-audio' in Payload.

Comment: Your package contains a file 'welldoneskatesupply.temp_caseinsensitive_rename.temp_caseinsensitive_rename 'with a name that cintains leading or trailing whitespec characters. –

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848712/changed-project-name-in-xcode-causing-naming-error)

Comment: how do I fix the invalid private key?

Comment: that answer didn't help.