# ?How to properly change an entire projects name in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I recently renamed a project in xcode and I thought I did it right, but then for some reason it said `case sensitive rename` at the end of the project.

*I know this question has no code, but I cant seem to find out how to properly change the entire project's name so I thought I'd ask via Stackoverflow.*

Does anyone know how to properly do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442867/how-do-i-rename-a-project-in-xcode-5) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416677/renaming-projects-in-xcode-4)? If you are looking for a pointer on Apple developer portal, here is one, [How do I rename my application in Xcode?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1625/_index.html)

I was about to take some screenshots of how I did project renaming but then, I found [this](http://matthewfecher.com/app-developement/xcode-tips-the-best-way-to-change-a-project-name-in-xcode/).

Easy as piece of cake :)