# Drupalgap developed IOS app not working after renaming from ExampleApp to a custom name

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, drupal

A hybrid app was developed using Drupalgap cordova for iOS. The project is named ExampleApp, as followed by a [tutorial](http://www.drupalgap.org/node/193), and once started in Xcode (5 and 6) the app works well in iOS simulator. Now I need to rename the app to a custom name to put it for submission in the App Store, but once I do that in Xcode, the app breaks. I followed the official Apple Support page to do that and the one here [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442867/how-do-i-rename-a-project-in-xcode-5) with no luck. The app is present on iOS iPhone simulator dashboard with the icon and a new name, but once it starts loading the splash screen, it breaks as soon as it loads it. What is the best way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

1. use the PhoneGap Command Line Interface to create a new "official" project: `cordova create OfficialApp com.official "OfficialApp"`
2. add the iOS xCode project files: `cordova platform add ios`
3. install the DrupalGap SDK on top of the empty project
4. copy the `www/app` folder from ExampleApp into your new empty project's `www/app` folder
5. prepare/build the app from the terminal
6. test in xCode simulator

Be sure to replace any custom modifications you had to the index.html file of your new Project. More info: http://drupalgap.org/node/193

Each step of the way, I'd recommend doing a prepare/build via the terminal and then launch the app via xCode to verify PhoneGap works out of the box, then DrupalGap works out of the box, then drop your app on top and run it.

If these steps don't work, I'd recommend opening up an issue in one of the queues:

http://www.drupalgap.org/support

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I will try to follow your advice and let you know if I had any luck.

Comment: I can now confirm this works nicely and the app loads well. Thank you very much for your suggested solution.