# Changing name destroys project ability to run! Xcode

Tags: file, linker, mach-o, invocation

I recently changed my project name and then I when I run I get a Apple Mach-O Linker error here it is.

```
ld: file not found: /Users/Ajay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TapAway-dzdhwbcfttcdcceccpophqtqgmvl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Speedy.app/Speedy
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Im not sure why this is happening can any one please help me Im really new.

Thanks for everyone who helped. 
Please be a bit specific I'm not that good.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Hopefully you had a Time Machine backup of your original project, because trying to repair the damage could be a big hassle.  Renaming a project is tricky, [and here is how to do it for Xcode 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442867/how-do-i-rename-a-project-in-xcode-5) (which shouldn't be too much different for Xcode 6).

Comment: I do want to change the name but I reverted it to the previous name and it works like a charm. Thanks for the tutorial, I will post back if it is useful. THX :)

Comment: Nope the tutorial does Exactly what I did!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So In the end I found the answer to my question! :)

Once you change the name of the project, under targets click on the white lego brick(Tests),
when you click it it will show one option called Host Application.

Click on the checkbox next to it and choose your file.

Look at the image.

[image: Solution]

Comment: Wow, I cannot tick my answer!