# Couldn't load a Xcode project with pods

Tags: xcode

I need help. Rename the schema of my project and the project did not return to work. Then I opened a backup of my project and when i open the project your name appears in red color looks like this:
http://pasteboard.co/zK5sPPo.png

I hope you can help me because i do not know how to fix this

Comment: I did as he says in the link but I deleted the project and download an earlier version and the name appears in red

Comment: Have you look that answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/19442868/3800154?  and how you are doing for rename a Project ?

Comment: yes, I rename the project as the link says but I deleted the bad project and i opened a backup project and this project has the name right. I think the files are poorly linked.

Comment: now i see this: http://pasteboard.co/zN6MKIb.png

Comment: https://gyazo.com/189f02e7a0e313f58d7501188873230d check this ..You have to like this