# Is there any better way to rename an XCode project than the given one?

Tags: ios, xcode

The given version is described here: [How do I rename a project in Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442867/how-do-i-rename-a-project-in-xcode-5)

But, as you can see from the following screenshot^, not everything gets renamed, and if one opens package contents, directory names etc. to try to manually change all the references, the project is broken afterwards, so you have to keep the old project name for sub directories etc., which granted is not a massive problem, but is intensely irritating, and I'm not enjoying being intensely irritated at work.

^ apologies for a screenshot, but there's too much information in it to transcribe to written text. Top two-thirds of screenshot is XCode project, bottom third a Finder window.

[image]

Comment: You might be better off starting from scratch with the new name and then bring the source and interface files over from the old project.  That way you know there won't be any residue of the old project and that should calm the irritation.

Comment: Maybe you're right @trojanfoe, I guess the tumbleweed on this post shows it's the only viable option really.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming projects in xcode in one of the most annoying things in iOS development. I assume you want to rename your app. I faced this problem once and figured out a simple, clean way to do it.

1. Go back to the point where everything worked.

   Open project in xcode and click on the project icon in the project structure( first file)

   Go to the info tab

   Search for `Bundle Name`. Most probably it will automatically be set to `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` which is a shell variable that will set your app name the same as the project name.

   Set it to whatever you want your app name to be

   Done

Notes :

If you use `custom URL Schemes` this might produce an error when redirecting.

ALWAYS git or some other SVN in your projects. This will come in handy in this kind of situations