# Ios app - need to change app name, but what happens to push notification certificates, provisioning profile and app ID?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I want to change the name of the iOS app that I created - that is, it should have a different name on the home screen. But I already created and installed Apple push development and production certificates with the current project name and bundle identifier. Will I have to re-generate new APN certificates? And also re-create the provisioning profile and app IDs? What's the best safe way to change the app's name ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For changing app name set `CFBundleDisplayName` value in `info.plist` file:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>New app name here</string>
```

Name specified in this way would be displayed on device under the app icon.
Push notification service depends on app bundle id `CFBundleIdentifier`.
So you needn't regenerate certificates.

Comment: for newbies like me... click on plist and open as 'source code' to see the format seen above

Answer (score 2):

Changing the app name or display name does not effect the push certificates.

Answer (score 0):

If the bundle identifier, which links your app to your app id (which in turn hold your APN certificate), hasn't change, your push notifications will keep on working.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - NO you does not need to regenerate new APN certificates? I have tried same as your requirement and I change my appName without any changes, it;s working for me. APNS/Certificate is base on bundleIdentifier, if you change it then problem will be occurs.

Comment: So then how did you change the app name then, without changing app identifier?

Comment: @RedRoses - look at this question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954015/how-to-change-xcode-project-name