# Changing Project Name textures render wrong : Cant reverse

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, rename

I changed the name of the app as it appears on the device under its icon by first changing the project name as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954015/how-to-change-xcode-project-name).

Suddenly on the simulator:

- the textures were not rendering correctly
- or could could not be found ( a large x appeared where the Sprtite Halo should of been)
- They were significantly freezes during run time
- The textures that did render were allot smaller

After panicking a bit I undid the change and everything was back to normal.
I then changed the name by changing the  Bundle Display Name, see link above.
Everything still worked fine on simulators and name did change on app icon.

To my dismay now running the app on a real device I can see the very same problems, although not evident in the emulator.

Tried deleting app from device. It looks like the device is using image from an old atlas and not rendering them correctly  ie a where a small 8kb spaceship should be is a chunk of a background image 600kb although the background image is no longer in the atlas of current project!!

Interestingly the same unwanted issues are seen in both simulators and device run form Xcode 6, but app runs as expected on Xcode 5.1 simulators.

Have cleaned and built several times.

Any suggestions welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

This could not be fixed, spent two days re-working an older version.
For those looking to change there project/app name please follow the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1625/_index.html).
By not following the second step caused me two days work and a mild yet uncomfortable heart attack.

The second step in Xcode 5.1.1, I had incorrectly chosen the default which had all checboxes checked and not just the Application as depicted below:
[image]