# Change the name of a project in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I have experimented some ways to change an Xcode project's name. however, none of them change the name everywhere. Is there a correct way to change Xcode projects name?

Comment: Here's what the official documentation says: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/RenamingaProject/RenamingaProject.html

Comment: @tuple_cat thanks....everything worked, but i had to change folder names manually, and re import the files...but worked...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the project title then hit enter and you will be able to change the name of the project as shown.

[image: this]

Answer (score 0):

[image]plz go to Build Settings -> packaging -> product name

set the name you want

Answer (score 0):

1) as pointed earlier this is covered here [how to change Xcode Project name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15444927/2027018)

2) the only thing to finish it completely is to change the name of the **scheme**. 
just duplicate it with new desired name and delete the old one.