# When using cocoapods, what is the best way to change the PRODUCT_NAME?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I created an app with name "ABC". Months later I decided to change the name to "ABCD". I believe the way I changed it, was in my Podfile, I changed `target "ABC" do` to `target "ABCD" do`. However, I recall going through quite a few issues/errors afterward in my workspace that caused a lot of stress. It was so long ago that I can't quite recall though.

Now I'm ready to submit, and I want to change the name one last time. I've changed the name in iTunes Connect, but now I want to change my PRODUCT_NAME, and my bundle identifier to match.

What is the best way to do this? Should I change the target fields in my Podfile? Or should I leave them, and just change something else in Xcode? Or do I need to change both or more than one thing?

Answer (score 13):

When you have a Pod file the `.xcworkspace` and `Pods.xcodeproj` is generated dynamically by the `pod install` process.

So one way to deal with this is

1. Change your product name
2. Close the project in Xcode
3. Discard the existing `.xcworkspace`, `Pods` folder & `Podfile.lock`
4. Run `pod install` again.

The cocoapods engine will regenerate its project, pull the Pods from its cache and recreate its `Pods.xcodeproj` with the new project settings.

This might be a little more complex in the case where you have other dependancies besides your main project and the `Pods` project in your workspace.

You'll probably want to have everything committed to source control before you do this so you can revert if it goes wrong.

Comment: You also need to change the configuration file setting in the project file - CocoaPods doesn't do that automatically. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27039447/2518722

Comment: I also need to delete Pods_{productname}.framework in my Xcode project's Pods folder.

Answer (score 7):

I solved if for my project with this steps.

1. I install cocoapods-deintegrate

   > [sudo] gem install cocoapods-deintegrate

   and call pod deintegrate on my project.
2. open XCode, click on project name and click again with delay to rename, follow xcode instructions

   [image]
3. run pod install again on your project.
4. NOTE: if you are just Capitalising, or Uppercassing project name do it with other temp name: for me locdel->aaa->Locdel.

Answer (score 0):

I've been scouting the internet to no avail looking for an answer to this. While editing the podfile and running pod install again fixes the renaming problem, in my case it broke my application as those pods had evolved while my app had stayed the same.
If you have concerns about backwards compatibility and don't want to reinstall your dependencies I suggest you do as I did and edit directly the .xcworkspace and .xcodeproj files using a text editor.